# Codeigniter Form validation Run at page load

Tags: codeigniter, validation

Hi i have a problem with form validation on this function it run false at PAGELOAD what did i do wrong?

- i use stencil template
- install codeiginiter in sub-folder after wordpress website

  ```
  public function create()        {

  $this->stencil->title('Tour');
  $this->stencil->layout('booktour_layout');
  $this->stencil->css('font-awesome');
  $this->stencil->paint('booktour_create');
  $this->load->helper('form');
  $this->load->library('form_validation');


  if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
  {

      echo "<script>alert('error');</script>";    

  }
  else
  {

      echo "<script>alert('success');</script>";  

  }       
  }
  ```

When i load the page it echo script at pageload not the submit form

Any though? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

put your code in isset function that mean it will not work without submit form.
please change  the index with any of our input name

```
if(isset($_POST['index'])) {

if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
{

    echo "<script>alert('error');</script>";    

}
else
{

    echo "<script>alert('success');</script>";  

} 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First check whether the POST is requested by using `if(isset($_POST)){<Your Validation Code;>}` OR `if(!empty($this->input->post())){<Your Validation Code;>}`

Hope this will help you in solving your problem

Comment: m glad to help u in solving the issue.if u like then plz up vote my answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As I remember, default result for validation is false. And only when values pass thru rules it sets to true. So while there is no rules, you will receive false.

Let me explain more. Write a controller:

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) { echo "<script>alert('error');</script>"; }
else { echo "<script>alert('success');</script>"; }
```

and call it without query. You will receive error. It means that you shoud check that query is present and add at least one rule before calling validation

Comment: yeah but it should be echo false after press submit right? but it echo at pageload , think is another controller that have the same code work just fine -_-

Comment: @Wolfcain i've extended my answer